# How to run a "replace order" in Word every other time

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, replace, ms-word

I have a sort of long document with all parentheses toward one side; like **(out of stock(**.
Now I'm wondering how I can write a replace order replacing every other parenthesis.

I already know that the replace order is like:

`Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content  myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="(", _  ReplaceWith:=")", Replace:=wdReplaceAll`

but unfortunately I don't know how to apply

`If i Mod 2 = 0 Then` 
to the code above.

Comment: I could fix the issue with the code [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-write-a-replace-order-in-vba-working-every/cb92c14a-6876-4556-94ed-d7efb008a4df)

Comment: You may run into issues with the every second method. If you do, I would look into regular expressions. [**REGEX**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)